# Cómo hacer que una aplicación de Consola que pida un dato, y reaccione dependiendo de la respuesta

Tags: vb.net, consola

en esta ocasión me gustaría resolver esto:
Mi duda es ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una aplicación de consola me pida un dato y reaccione según la respuesta?
Les dejo un fragmento de mi código:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    'Datos de la versión
    Console.WriteLine("Modo a prueba de fallos")
    Console.WriteLine("Kevin Figueroa")
    Console.WriteLine("Copyright 2017")
    Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************************")
    Console.WriteLine()

    'Menú Principal
A:      Console.WriteLine("¡Sea Bienvenido!")
    Console.WriteLine("Por favor, indique una sección para poder empezar a trabajar")
    Console.WriteLine("Para saber qué términos puede usar, escriba 'Términos'")
    Console.ReadLine()

    Dim SelecciónMenúPrincipal As String
    SelecciónMenúPrincipal = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case SelecciónMenúPrincipal
        Case "Términos"
            Console.WriteLine("[Ayuda] - Muestra el Centro de Ayuda en Html.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Acercade] - Muestra datos de GeckLab como su autor o la versión.")
            Console.WriteLine("[HerrBásicas] - Abre la sección 'Herramientas Básicas'.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Conversores] -  Abre la sección de los conversores, entre ellos está el de peso.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Salir] - Cierra la aplicación.")
    End Select

    GoTo A
End Sub

End Module
```

Lo que quiero es que cuando ponga "Términos" me despliegue un menú con las opciones disponibles, intenté con la instrucción If  De esta manera.

```
  Console.ReadLine()
  SelecciónMenúPrincipal = Console.ReadLine

  If SelecciónMenúPrincipal = "Términos" Then
  Console.WriteLine("[Ayuda] - Muestra el Centro de Ayuda en Html.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Acercade] - Muestra datos de GeckLab como su autor o la versión.")
            Console.WriteLine("[HerrBásicas] - Abre la sección 'Herramientas Básicas'.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Conversores] -  Abre la sección de los conversores, entre ellos está el de peso.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Salir] - Cierra la aplicación.")

    End If
     GoTo A
```

Pero no pasó nada al poner "Términos".
También intenté con Select Case, pero nada. (El código del select case, es el primero)
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Kevin,

Lo estás haciendo bien, las 2 formas que nos muestras són buenas.

El fallo que tienes aquí es que no estás obteniendo la palara bien en la variable, ya que ejecutas el `Console.ReadLine` 2 veces:

```
Console.ReadLine()
SelecciónMenúPrincipal = Console.ReadLine
```

---

```
Console.ReadLine()

Dim SelecciónMenúPrincipal As String
SelecciónMenúPrincipal = Console.ReadLine()
```

Para obtener la palabra bien tienes que ejecutar la instrucción `Console.ReadLine()` una sola vez poniendola en la variable String, te quedaría de ésta forma:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()

    'Datos de la versión
    Console.WriteLine("Modo a prueba de fallos")
    Console.WriteLine("Kevin Figueroa")
    Console.WriteLine("Copyright 2017")
    Console.WriteLine("*****************************************************************")
    Console.WriteLine()

    'Menú Principal
A:      Console.WriteLine("¡Sea Bienvenido!")
    Console.WriteLine("Por favor, indique una sección para poder empezar a trabajar")
    Console.WriteLine("Para saber qué términos puede usar, escriba 'Términos'")

    Dim SelecciónMenúPrincipal As String
    SelecciónMenúPrincipal = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case SelecciónMenúPrincipal
        Case "Términos"
            Console.WriteLine("[Ayuda] - Muestra el Centro de Ayuda en Html.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Acercade] - Muestra datos de GeckLab como su autor o la versión.")
            Console.WriteLine("[HerrBásicas] - Abre la sección 'Herramientas Básicas'.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Conversores] -  Abre la sección de los conversores, entre ellos está el de peso.")
            Console.WriteLine("[Salir] - Cierra la aplicación.")
    End Select

    GoTo A
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: ¡gracias! ya había encontrado este método y me funcionó de maravilla, ahora puedo seguir trabajando en modo consola.